# Optional / Conditional String Concatination

Tags: java, string, concatenation

I am trying to concatenate `String` conditionally. For example in a method I have two parameters and a local `String` variable. If i provide values for those parameters then those values will be added to the local `String` variable.

```java
public Object concatinateString(String a, String b){

   String xyz = "firstValue";

   if((a == null || a == "") && (b != null || b != "")) {

        xyz = xyz.concat(".").concat(b);
   }

   if((b == null || b == "") && (a != null || a != "")) {

        xyz = xyz.concat(".").concat(a);
   }

   xyz = xyz.concat(".").concat(a).concat(".").concat(b);
}
```

**what i expect:**

```java
  concatinateString(null, b) --> xyz = firstValue.b;

  concatinateString("", b) --> xyz = firstValue.b

  concatinateString(a, null) --> xyz = firstValue.a

  concatinateString(a, "") --> xyz = firstValue.a

  concatinateString("", "") --> xyz = firstValue

  concatinateString(null, null) --> xyz = firstValue

  concatinateString(a, b) --> xyz = firstValue.a.b
```

I have also tried those following code but not getting the expected result.

```java
public Object concatinateString(Optional<String> stageName, Optional<String> systemName) {
        Optional<String> property = Optional.of("firstValue");

        if ((!stageName.isPresent() || stageName.equals("")) && systemName.isPresent()) {

            property = Stream.of(property, systemName).flatMap(x -> x.map(Stream::of).orElse(null)).reduce((a, b) -> a + "." + b);

        }
        if (((!systemName.isPresent() || systemName.equals(""))) && stageName.isPresent()) {
            property = Stream.of(property, stageName).flatMap(x -> x.map(Stream::of).orElse(null)).reduce((a, b) -> a + "." + b);
        }
        property = Stream.of(property, stageName, systemName)
                .flatMap(x -> x.map(Stream::of).orElse(null))
                .reduce((a, b) -> a + "." + b);

        return property;

    }


 public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person person = new Person();
        System.out.println(person.concatinateString(Optional.ofNullable(null),Optional.ofNullable(null)));
}
```

**Result i am getting:**

```java
  concatinateString(null, b) --> xyz = firstValue.b.b

  concatinateString("", b) --> xyz = firstValue..b

  concatinateString(a, null) --> xyz = firstValue.a.a

  concatinateString(a, "") --> xyz = firstValue.a.

  concatinateString("", "") --> xyz = firstValue..

  concatinateString(null, null) --> xyz = firstValue

  concatinateString(a, b) --> xyz = firstValue.a.b
```

Answer (score 0):

if I understand your question correctly, your problem was in the conditions. Indeed, if you want to get  firstvalue + b, a must be equal to "" or null, but b must be different from "" AND null. But your condition says b != "" || b != null. Here's the way i see this:

```
if ((a != "" && a != null) && (b == "" || b == null)){

    firstvalue + a;

} else if ((b != "" && b != null) && (a == "" || a == null)) {

    firstvalue + b;

} else if ((a != "" && a != null) && (b != "" && b != null)) {

    firstvalue + a + b;

} else if ((a == "" || a == null) && (b == "" || b == null)) {

    firstvalue;

}
```

It should return what you expected:

concatinateString(a, null) --> xyz = firstValue.a

concatinateString(a, "") --> xyz = firstValue.a

concatinateString(null, b) --> xyz = firstValue.b;

concatinateString("", b) --> xyz = firstValue.b

concatinateString(a, b) --> xyz = firstValue.a.b

concatinateString("", "") --> xyz = firstValue

concatinateString(null, null) --> xyz = firstValue

Adding this too:

concatinateString(null, "") --> xyz = firstValue

concatinateString("", null) --> xyz = firstValue

I hope this solution will do. Bye !

Answer (score 0):

If you need more explanations, let's decode your first condition :

```
if((a == null || a == "") && (b != null || b != "")) {

        xyz = xyz.concat(".").concat(b);
   }
```

Here, what's important is this part : (b != null || b != "").
Indeed, let's see the case where b == null.

```
If b == null, (b != null) returns 0, and (b != "") returns 1.

In this case, (0 || 1) returns 1. But, it should return 0.
```

Now if b == "".

```
If b == "", (b != null) returns 1, and (b != "") returns 0.

Here, (1 || 0) returns 1. But again, it should return 0.
```

Now if you put && instead of || in (b != null || b != ""),

```
If b == null, (b != null) returns 0, and (b != "") returns 1.

(1 && 0) returns 0.

If b == "", (b != null) returns 1, and (b != "") returns 0.

(0 && 1) returns 0.
```

Then only if b is different from both "" and null you'll have :
(1 && 1) that returns 1 and concatinates b to xyz.

Hope it helps.